# Прямая речь перед словами автора

Tags: прописная, строчная

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. У Розенталя упоминается такое правило:

> Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой
>   отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы: — Скорей,
>   загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Действует ли это правило, если слова автора, оформленные тоже как отдельное предложение с прямым порядком слов, передают мимику, жесты или действия, происходящие одновременно с речью, а не после нее? И глаголов "сказал", "ответил" и т. п. в них нет. Например, типа таких предложений:

— А зачем вам это? — Прохожий нахмурился.

— Так даже лучше! — Собеседница радостно всплеснула руками.

Или в таких случаях слова автора пишутся со строчной?

Answer (score 3):

> Действует ли это правило, если слова автора, оформленные тоже как отдельное предложение с прямым порядком слов, передают мимику, жесты или действия, происходящие одновременно с речью, а не после нее? И глаголов "сказал", "ответил" и т. п. в них нет. Например, типа таких предложений:

Helen, правило это очень простое. Оно никак не связано с одновременностью действия или его видом. Если предложение после прямой речи представляет собой слова автора, **грамматически** не связанные с прямой речью, то в любом случае слова автора начинаются с заглавной (я опускаю все замысловатости формулировок ради смысла).

Сморите. Есть, допустим, прямая речь: *"А зачем вам это?" - сказал прохожий.*

Здесь прямая речь отвечает на вопрос "что сказал", слово "сказал" есть в речи автора. Отсюда прямая речь представляет собой часть общего предложения, слова автора начинаются со строчной.

Ваш пример. *"А зачем вам это?" - Прохожий нахмурился.* 
Здесь нет слова "сказал" или подобного, для которого прямая речь стала бы ответом на вопрос, что сделал. (Вариант *прохожий нахмурился "а зачем вам это?"* не предлагать). Поэтому и буква заглавная.

Ищите авторское слово, глагол, для которого прямая речь будет ответом на вопрос, что именно сделал. Сказал, подумал, сигналит, будет петь, показал жестом - это все подходит. На все эти глаголы в составе вопроса "что сделал" может отвечать прямая речь. Время действия, последовательность и его принцип абсолютно не важны.

Это правило годится на все случаи. Иногда, правда, бывают случаи спорные, когда можно и так и эдак трактовать, но даже это очень большая редкость, так что не ошибетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Слова автора всегда пишутся со строчной буквы. Справочник Розенталя(книга издательства "Оникс 21 век", тот же справочник этого издательства 2011 года этого примечания уже не содержит),а также Справочник "Трудные случае пунктуации", Д.Э. Розенталь, Былинский, - это два единственных издания, где содержится такая рекомендация. Нет и упоминания о прописной буквы ни у Лопатина, ни у Валгиной.

Однако в справочнике "Трудные случае пунктуации", Д.Э. Розенталь, Былинский, есть следующая рекомендация:
Если прямая речь начинается с абзаца, то двоеточие после предшествующих авторских слов ставится не всегда.

1. Оно ставится, если авторские слова содержат
   в себе глагол со значением ***речи или мысли*** {говорить,
   сказать, рассказать, заметить, обратиться, подумать, вос-
   кликнуть, закричать, прошептать, спросить, спрашивать,
   ответить, прервать, вставить, заговорить, начать, продол-
   жать, подтвердить, пояснить, согласиться, поддакнуть,
   напомнить, посоветовать, упрекнуть, решить и т, п.) или
   существительное, близкое по значению или образованию
   к глаголам, обозначающим речь или мысль (вопрос, ответ,
   слова, восклицание, голос, шепот, звук и т. п.). В каче-
   стве глаголов, 'замещающих собой слова со значением
   речи или мысли, могут быть использованы глаголы, обо-
   значающие чувства, ощущения, эмоции говорящего, его
   внутреннее состояние (вспомнить, удивиться, обрадо-
   ваться, огорчиться, обидеться, возмутиться, ужаснуться
   и т. п.), ***а также глаголы, обозначающие мимику, жесты,
   движения (улыбнуться, рассмеяться, усмехнуться, захохо-
   тать, вздохнуть, нахмуриться, подойти, подбежать, вско-
   чить и т. п.).*** Хотя и те и другие глаголы сами по себе не
   определяют необходимости следования за ними прямой
   речи, однако они, как правило, **допускают возможность
   добавить к ним глагол речи или мысли** (вспомнил и ска-
   зал, удивился и спросил, обрадовался и закричал, возму-
   тился и прервал, нахмурился и произнес, подбежал и вое-
   кликнул и т. д.) **и  поэтому воспринимаются как глаголы,
   вводящие прямую речь, и после них ставится двоеточие.**
   Хотя и справочнике нет примеров с этими глаголами, вводящие прямую речь,
   тем не менее,  как видно из рекомендации, эти глаголы воспринимаются как вводящие прямую речь, а следовательно должны писаться со строчной буквы.

Если все же Вам необходимо графически выделить слова автора, можно использовать следующий порядок:

— А зачем вам это?

Прохожий нахмурился.

Собеседница радостно всплеснула руками.

— Так даже лучше!

***Ср.пример из этого справочника.***

Брови его нахмурились.

— Я не разрешаю этого делать.

Но обоих справочник содержащих пример слов автора с прописной, нет глаголов вводящих прямую речь.

— Ребята, машина приехала! — И Коля побежал дальше, чтобы успеть предупредить всех. (пример из справочника "Трудные случае пунктуации").

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

***Кстати, обратите внимание: это два почти анологичных примера.***

Comment: Откуда это все?

Comment: И где ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Вы не разобравшись, ставите минус. А сами даете неправильный ответ . Потому что вы даже не читали, что я написал. Лишь бы напакостить. У Розенталя говорится, что  слова выражающие мимику, жесты, воспринимаются как слова вводящие прямую речь. И, как всегда, наверное, Розенталь ошибся.

Comment: Нет, я разобрался. И минус вполне заслуженный. Впрочем, это не обсуждается.

Comment: Розенталь обычно прав. Правда, если сравнить издания прижизненные и последующие вопросы, . Но Вы-то все равно не Розенталь. Если Вы даете на него ссылку, не понимая смысла там написанного, это еще не право говорить от имени Дитмара Эльяшевича.

Comment: *У Розенталя говорится, что слова выражающие мимику, жесты, воспринимаются как слова вводящие прямую речь*  - у него много чего написано. Минус не за это. А за словоблудие, в котором трудно найти ответ. Вы так озабочены, что Вас заподозрят в незнании, что  пересказываете целые параграфы, хотя вопрос яйца выеденного не стоит.

Comment: Как раз это прижизненное издание, т.е. старое. Даже если был бы не Розенталь, это не дает вам право сомневаться в точности материала.

Comment: Кстати, та чем мой-то ответ неправильный? Ну хоть кто-то может возразить по сути кроме детской обиды? Я-то вменяемую речь понимаю.

Comment: Как раз словоблудие у вас, а не у меня. Я лишь то, что в учебнике. И , в отличии от вас, не занимаюсь отсебятиной.

Comment: *Даже если был бы не Розенталь, это не дает вам право сомневаться в точности материала* - во первых, забудьте. Я имею право сомневаться во всем и буду это делать по мере надобности. Здесь догматики не в почете. А во-вторых, вопрос так не стоит. Я сомневаюсь в адекватности не Розенталя, а Сержа. И у меня есть масса причин это делать. Где, например, в Вашем тексте ответ на поставленный вопрос? И где в моем неточность?

Comment: А в том неправильный, что Вы себя считаете умнее лингвистов. Почему-то вам кажется, что везде ошибки. Только все ваши ответы верны. Автора интересовал вопрос, пишутся ли слова автора с прописной буквы, если они передают мимику, жесты. Я ответил, сославшись на Розенталя. Вы же практически оспариваете Розенталя, ставите под сомнение его учебник, и говорите, что здесь надо писать с прописной. Так докажите со ссылкой на учебник, что слова автора передающии мимику, жесту пишутся с прописной буквы.

Comment: *Как раз словоблудие у вас, а не у меня. Я лишь то, что в учебнике. И , в отличии от вас, не занимаюсь отсебятиной.* - это ваше мнение. У меня оно противоположно. Впрочем, не важно. Вы можете ответить на простой вопрос? Или опять на личности перейдете? Где в вашем ответе что-то, что можно считать ответом на вопрос о том, с какой буквы должна идти речь автора?

Comment: Сомневаться имеете право, но прежде чем писать, что в учебнике ошибка, надо это доказать.

Comment: Я ответил. Слова автора, передающие мимику, жесты ( по Розенталю), пишутся со строчной. Т.к. они являются словами, вводящими прямую речь. И отметил, что можно оформить по-другому, если нужно писать с прописной. И опять-таки привел пример из справочника.

Comment: В моем ответе вы не имеете право сомневаться. Я никогда ничего не пишу от себя. В отличии от вас.

Comment: *А в том неправильный, что Вы себя считаете умнее лингвистов. * - а где я такое написал? Я не считаю себя умнее "лингвистов". Это Вы о себе любимом во множественном числе? Я считаю себя человеком с IQ достаточным чтобы нажать минус на ответ который мне лично не нравится по причинам  неадекватности его  вопросу.

Comment: Этим все и сказано.

Comment: *Слова автора, передающие мимику, жесты ( по Розенталю), пишутся со строчной. Т.к. они являются словами, вводящими прямую речь* - А какое это отношение имеет к вопросу? Там про эти жесты вообще вскользь упомянуто. А если бы и так, это что дает вам право отождествлять себя с Розенталем? Вы не Розенталь, как бы Вам этого не хотелось.

Comment: *Этим все и сказано* - нет, не все. Мне еще интересно, Вы и дальше намерены на вопросы подобным образом отвечать? Это Вам не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий к ответу участника @Серж**

Серж, как вы думаете, чем объяснить **взаимонепонимание** в этой теме? Строчная или прописная буква? Вроде бы позиции отвечающих правильны, каждый уверен в своей правоте.

Может быть, надо пользоваться более **точной, а не описательной** терминологией? Вот наш участник определяет разницу в примерах, но точной характеристики там нет, как **нет и специальных терминов.**

И через 8 лет  мы по-прежнему используем только примеры и описания, но есть же такие понятия, как  **атрибуция, атрибутивные глаголы.** Надо ли их использовать, какую оценку вы можете им дать?

**[Из ответов 2024 года](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480039/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)**

**ОПИСАТЕЛЬНЫЙ МЕТОД**

**2016 год**

```
 Здесь прямая речь отвечает на вопрос "что сказал", 
 слово "сказал" есть в речи автора. Отсюда прямая 
 речь представляет собой часть общего предложения, 
 слова автора начинаются со строчной.
 Ваш пример. "А зачем вам это?" - Прохожий 
 нахмурился. Здесь нет слова "сказал" или подобного, 
 для которого прямая речь стала бы ответом на 
 вопрос, что сделал.  Поэтому и буква заглавная.
 Ищите авторское слово, глагол, для которого прямая 
 речь будет ответом на вопрос, что именно сделал.
```

**2024 год**

```
  Как именно понять, что слова автора не связаны с 
  прямой речью и являются отдельным предложением?
  Их, собственно, и можно записать отдельным 
  предложением — с нового абзаца, оторвав от чьих-то 
  слов (в нашем случае это описание особенностей 
  речи, произношения).
```

Answer (score 0):

В приведенных примрах пишется **прописная буква.**

*— А зачем вам это? — Прохожий нахмурился.*

*— Так даже лучше! — Собеседница радостно всплеснула руками.*

Здесь **авторская речь** как отдельное предложение (прописная буква), а не **слова автора**, или атрибуция (приписывание).

Определить это можно по глаголам, которые **не являются атрибутивными,** а также по **прямому порядку слов.**

[Атрибутивные глаголы](https://blog.selfpub.ru/atributciya)

```
   Все глаголы, которые авторы используют в диалогах, можно 
   разделить на однозначно атрибутивные, условно- 
   атрибутивные, сомнительно-атрибутивные и **вовсе не 
   атрибутивные**.
   С глаголами вовсе не атрибутивными, казалось бы, все 
   понятно — они не поясняют, кто или как произносит 
   реплику, а лишь сопутствуют действиям. Однако довольно 
   часто приходится читать что-нибудь вроде:
   — Вот и я так подумал, — затянулся сигаретой Олег.
```