# Как правильно расставить знаки в прямой речи и словах автора?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком случае после прямой речи ставится точка и слова автора пишутся с большой буквы?**

Разобралась, что знаки ставятся таким образом, когда слова автора не связаны с прямой речью и выступают в качестве отдельного предложения. Но как именно понять, что они не связаны с прямой речью и являются отдельным предложением?

*Например, в этом случае:*

*— Да, вы правильно меня поняли (?) — (О/о)н говорил чётко и уверенно и не обращал внимания на осуждающие взгляды.*

В этом предложении есть пояснение прямой речи, однако слова расставлены в другом порядке (не "...— сказал он чётко и уверенно...", а именно как это писалось бы в обычном тексте без прямой речи).

Считаются ли такие и другие подобные слова автора отдельным предложением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Слова автора как атрибуция**

   **АТРИБУЦИЯ** [лат. attributio — приписывание]

[Значение слова «атрибут»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82)

В широком смысле слова этот термин означает **приписывание объекту** каких-то характеристик, свойств, особенностей. А в литературе **атрибуция – это слова автора**, поясняющие реплики персонажей. Например:

```
 – Ты завтра придёшь? – спросил с надеждой Олег.
 – Нет, у меня завтра много дел. – Девушка сокрушённо 
 вздохнула, показывая, что от неё здесь ничего не зависит.
```

[Зачем нужна атрибуция в диалогах](https://dzen.ru/a/Xn41CQ0MrzdpKOH3)

2. **Правила оформления атрибуции (слов автора)  и авторской речи**

Кроме всем известных правил из Розенталя и ПАС, в Сети есть  различные **рекомендации по оформлению** атрибуции. Конечно, хотелось бы ссылаться на авторитетные/официальные **источники**, но их еще надо найти. Да и сведения  приводятся разные: к примеру, предлагают **различать** атрибуцию и авторскую речь.

**Атрибуция** указывает на того, кто говорит. Это обычное оформление по правилам. Но есть еще **авторская речь**, которая сопровождает диалог (описание действий и характеристика персонажей, их речи).

**Интересно!**

Описание сопутствующего реплике **жеста, мимики** вполне **может заменить** «говорительный» глагол. С другой стороны, избыточность подобных действий делает персонажей «нервными», если это не соответствует замыслу, то лучше убрать ненужные «телодвижения».

```
 — Ты с ума сошла?! — закатил глаза Петя.
 — Это ты сошел с ума! — топнула ногой Аня.
```

[Атрибутивные глаголы](https://blog.selfpub.ru/atributciya)

Все глаголы, которые авторы используют в диалогах, можно разделить на однозначно атрибутивные (сказал), условно-атрибутивные (улыбнулся), сомнительно-атрибутивные (закатил глаза) и **вовсе не атрибутивные.**

**Ошибка!** — *Вот и я так подумал, — затянулся сигаретой Олег.*

3. Рассмотрим **заданный пример**:

*— **Да, вы правильно меня поняли**. — Он говорил чётко и уверенно и не обращал внимания на осуждающие взгляды.*

Это скорее **авторская речь** в виде отдельного предложения, но не атрибуция:

(1) Здесь нет  обычной/ожидаемой инверсии глагола говорения: ***сказал он***.  Использован **прямой** порядок слов: ***он говорил***.

(2) Вместо  ***сказал*** (сов. вид) используется ***говорил*** (несов. вид) как **характеристика** сказанного.

Авторская речь **нераспространенная**, незначительно отличается от стандартной атрибуции, поэтому не стоит выносить ее в отдельный абзац.

**Материалы по теме**:

[В помощь писателям: «говорительные» глаголы в диалогах](https://ficwriter.info/stati/321-kak-napisat-knigu-q/metody-i-priemy/7770-govoritelnye-glagoly-v-dialogakh.html)

[Атрибуция. Авторская речь. Пунктуация в диалогах](https://liosta.ru/attribution/)

[Самые распространенные ошибки в диалогах](https://dzen.ru/a/XWTIg4YA4QCtwyyb)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420453/Прямая-речь-перед-словами-автора](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420453/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) Вопрос задан 8 лет 1 месяц назад. Изменён 7 лет 11 месяцев назад Просмотрен 3k раза.

Answer (score 2):

Как именно понять, что слова автора не связаны с прямой речью и являются отдельным предложением?

Их, собственно, и можно записать отдельным предложением — с нового абзаца, оторвав от чьих-то слов (в нашем случае это описание особенностей речи, произношения).

• Вот два возможных варианта оформления

*— Да, вы правильно меня поняли. — **Он** говорил чётко и уверенно и не обращал внимания на осуждающие взгляды.*

*— Да, вы правильно меня поняли.

**Он** говорил чётко и уверенно и не обращал внимания на осуждающие взгляды.*

•• Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса

*— Ну будет, будет! — **Он** говорил отрывисто, будто бил кувалдой. Клаве показалось, что он выпивши* (Владимир Чивилихин. Про Клаву Иванову).

*— До вечера через любые каналы выясни, кто и когда из них пересекался с нашим Баландиным. — **Он** говорил быстро, напористо, и смышленый Подлесный подобрался охотником, учуявшим, что на него гонят близкую дичь* (Семен Данилюк. Рублевая зона).

*— Господи, да мы же с вами знакомы. У Насти и виделись… Забыли меня, должно быть…

**Он** говорил быстро, весело и нервно, как всякий добрый русский алкоголик, предвкушающий хорошую выпивку в хорошей компании* (Алексей Рыбин. Последняя игра).

*— Ну что же, господа, — блок? Надо что-то делать! Ведь положение-то… плохо. Вы собираетесь что-нибудь сделать?

**Он** говорил громко, подходя. Мы сошлись на середине зала* (В. В. Шульгин. Последний очевидец).

••• Вот тут еще есть информация:
[Когда слова автора после слов персонажа пишутся с прописной буквы?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/442910/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B/443370#443370)
[Может ли авторский текст, разделяющий прямую речь, начинаться с прописной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441614/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9/441617#441617)

Comment: Сорри, случайная правка.